# stuck on understanding memory alignment

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-alignment

[The code](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect2/blob/master/src/frame_listener_impl.cpp#L49-L54) allocating memory holding an image of `width * height` is as follows:

```
  const size_t alignment = 64;
  size_t space = width * height * bytes_per_pixel + alignment;
  rawdata = new unsigned char[space];
  //typedef unsigned long int uintptr_t
  uintptr_t ptr = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(rawdata); 
  uintptr_t aligned = (ptr - 1u + alignment) & -alignment; 
  data = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(aligned);
```

It seems that the 64-bytes alignment was performed on `rawdata`(i.e. the initially allocated memory), which generated aligned memory pointed by `data`. But, what puzzled me was the line:

```
uintptr_t aligned = (ptr - 1u + alignment) & -alignment
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Note that's this is a kind-of outdated hack to obtain over-aligned memory. C++ supports asking for such memory since C++17. Before, you can use some non-standard functions, such as `posix_memalign` on POSIX systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That calculation makes sure the address is aligned to the amount given (which must be a power of 2). This means the lowest `n` bits must be zero when alignment is `2^n`.

Let’s do it in binary. Let’s assume we get a random pointer aligned at 16 bytes while we want it to be aligned at 64 bytes and calculate. (This assumes two’s complement, which is not guaranteed, by the way, but is de facto standard):

```
address = ...1101010000
address - 1 -> ...1101001111
address + 64 -> ...1110001111
-alignment -> ...1111000000
address & -alignment -> ...1110000000
```

So in effect it finds the smallest value that is divisible by alignment due to `-alignment` having all bits zero below the alignment spot. It also assures it’s larger than original pointer by adding `alignment-1`, which is the negation of `-alignment` as bits, that is all top bits zero but lower ones one.

What if the address is already aligned? Then the calculation results in the original pointer since it has lowest bits zero, you make all lowest bits to one, then AND them away.

Comment: @Amadeus it is stated in the code that `uintptr_t` is `typedef`d as `unsigned long int`, so there's no pointer arithmetic, only integer arithmetic.

Comment: @Sami Kuhmonen Thanks for your elaboration. New aligned `address` is at least 63 larger than  raw unaligned `address`,  which explains the need of additional memory(as `size_t space = width * height * bytes_per_pixel + alignment` does), So how about `size_t space = width * height * bytes_per_pixel + alignment-1`? :)

Comment: @Finley Yes, I was going to add that but decided not to :) 63 bytes would be enough for additional space since it will never be more than that.